# Responsive, cross-browser and pure Javascript solution to show a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, cross-browser, modal-dialog

The modal dialog will show visitors with outdated browsers that they should upgrade. Small screens must be supported so the text size is important.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaand what have you tried??

Comment: I tried the method known as Absolute Centering in CSS to support old browsers. http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Comment: What I intended to ask is if there is a known method that solves this problem using pure Javascript for the text size.

Comment: it is possible by using percent like font-size: 50%; in your css

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already I would recommend you checking out Bootstrap Modal:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Since this is a well managed framework it should be optimized for most browsers.